# Can't access view

Tags: node.js, couchbase

Here's my view in the admin console:

[image]
Here's my code to call it via the API:

```
var query = cb.view('_design/dev_user/', 'by_name');
    console.log(query);
    query.query(function(err, results) {
        console.log(err);
        });
```

This is the output:

> { _cb:     { queryhosts: null,
>        mchosts: '',
>        srvhost: null,
>        hosts: 'localhost:8091',
>        _cb: { _handleRestResponse: [Function] },
>        connected: false },   ddoc: '_design/dev_user',   name: 'by_name',   q: {} }
>
> { [Error: REST error: bad_request] code: 4104,
>   reason: 'attachments not supported in Couchbase' }

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You must publish the view and query the resulted production view, not the dev view.

Answer (score 0):

You can call view by this way :

```
cb.view("dev_user", "by_name", {stale:false}).query(function(err, results) 
{
  console.log(err);
});
```